# gcc -Wextra warning comparison between signed and unsigned

Tags: gcc, compiler-warnings, gcc-warning

I have started making use of the compiler options **-Wall** and **-Wextra**

Compiling my one .c file with -Wall I get no warnings.

for -Wextra I get just 3 warnings and they are for 123, 552, and 881 .  At each of those lines the code is the same and is exactly this:

```
  for ( index = 0; index < strlen(str); index++ )
```

with the warning issued by -Wextra being

```
mycode.c:123: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned
mycode.c:552: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned
mycode.c:881: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned
```

the variable `index` in the given functions is defined/declared locally as an `int` and I know `strlen()` provided by `string.h` returns type `size_t`

what is the best way to write that line of code so there is no warning message generated?

Comment: ...using `unsigned` (or `size_t`) as a loop index? You're starting at 0, counting upward, and negative indices are possibly an error anyway, so it seems like a no-brainer...

Comment: Have you tried making `index` a `size_t`?  That also avoids the problem where `strlen` `return`s a result that's outside the range of `int` (e.g., you have an immensely long string).

Comment: @DevSolar: the loop index is the variable `index`.  It is defined locally as an`int`... the loop index is `int`.  `strlen` returns type `size_t`

Comment: Yes, and yes. And the best way to make the warning go away is to turn `index` into an `unsigned` / `size_t`. It's cleaner coding anyway.

Comment: I do not have nor expect to have an immensely long string, `str` is 1024 bytes long and checks are done for all that stuff.  `str` is the prefix to a file name.